# Where are there details about Set's use of a Desert's Night?

Tags: lore, adnd-2e, planescape

In the ADnD 2e Planescape adventure *Dead Gods* there's a passage that says

> Skorpios knew, of course, that the desert‘s night could be prepared as
>   part of an herbal drink that brought back memories stolen by the River
>   Styx. Such a flower could not grow here in Ankhwugaht without the
>   Master‘s strict attention and desire, so Skorpios was sure that **Set
>   (may he be praised and feared) must at one time have had need of such
>   a potion.**

I want to know more about that, but there's never more detail about it in the adventure. When and why did Set need the Desert's Night and in what book can I find more about this?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 7):

### There is none

There is only one other mention *detailing* the *Desert's Night* in all of *Planescape*, or D&D 2e's book, in *Planes of Law: Baator*, page 21:

> Ankhwugaht's fields produce the intoxicating blossom known as *desert's night*, a sedative said to set one's mind wandering. For an exceedingly high price (usually about 1,000 gp a blossom), a traveler can purchase the deadly bloom. It's used by sniffing the flower, which requires a save versus poison. A failed save sends the user into raging paranoia, and if he's not cured within 3 days, he goes berserk and attacks everyone in sight until he's cut down. A sucessful save, however, means he spends an enjoyable and profound day exploring his own mind, recovering memories sand healing psychic damages. This is the only known remedy for restoring memories lost to the Styx (save versus spell a t-6; success indicates a restored memory).

Which doesn't say anything about the god using the flower.

The flower is also mentioned as a pit fiend's treasure found in the *Temple of Neheod in Hell* dungeon from the adventure *A Paladin in Hell*. It is also mentioned briefly here and there on several other books as "the flower that can restore memories" everytime that *Ankhwugaht* is also mentioned, but not much is developed on that.

I found no (Egyptian) mythology legends about Set losing (or restoring) his memory either (there is no such thing similar to the *Styx* in Egyptian myth). That tale makes little sense and must have been an adventure hook for GM's to work with when necessary. So, I believe the author is trying to say that Set must have *some* reason to be growing the only thing on the metaplanes able to cure the mind wiping effect caused by the *River Styx*, and he might have needed that flower before, so he is keeping it growing for when he needs it again. But the exact reason is never given to us.